# Android Wear: Listen to incoming notifications

Tags: service, notifications, listener, wear-os

Is it possible to listen for incoming notifications in an Wearable Android App? I have tried to implement a *NotificationListenerService*, but the service's *onNotificationPosted()* is never called:

```
public class MyListenerService extends NotificationListenerService {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d("NotificationListener", "This works....");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        Log.i("NotificationListener", "... but this method won't be called.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to use a `NotificationListenerService` in Android Wear as there is no screen for the user to allow this. 
You have to do it in the device's app and to use the [Wearable Data Layer API](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html) to perform the action on Wear's side.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how to use wearable data layer API to listen for notification on Wear's side.

Comment: The link is pretty straight forward. On the Android handheld device, you listen to incoming notifications. When you receive one, you send a `Message` using the `MessageApi` with the data you need.

Comment: I mean to listen for sms, missed call etc. notification.

Comment: You have plenty of examples on how to use the `NotificationListenerService` on Google. For example: https://github.com/kpbird/NotificationListenerService-Example

Comment: NotificationListenerService does not work in android wear! My question is how to listen for sms notification received in android wear side?

Comment: That was the point of may answer. You can't on Wear. You have to do it on the handheld device and *then* sync it to your Wear device using the MessageApi.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

`adb shell settings put secure enabled_notification_listeners com.google.android.wearable.app/com.google.android.clockwork.stream.NotificationCollectorService:$YOUR_PACKAGE/$YOUR_PACKAGE.$YOUR_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER`