# ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS in android wear

Tags: wear-os

I want to write an application that manages "Do Not Disturb" settings in an Android Wear 2.0 device. All code pasted below is working fine in an Android phone.

Reading current interruption setting requires permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
```

On phone and wearable current state can be retrieved using:

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
int state = mNotificationManager.getCurrentInterruptionFilter();
```

Do Not Disturb state can be set with this code:

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.setInterruptionFilter(NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_PRIORITY);
```

This requires "access to Do Not Disturb configuration". Otherwise a security exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Notification policy access denied
```

This permission can be requested by starting a configuration activity on mobile:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

On wearable this causes an exception:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS }
```

This means that this configuration activity is not available in wearable settings. Is there another option how this permission can be granted to application?

Answer (score 0):

Notification Policy Access Settings activity is not available in Wear and Google knows about this. A feature request is available in their system: [Support for notification listener services](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37135679).

Alternatively the Notification Listener permission can be granted via ADB as described here: [Android Wear: Listen to incoming notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27185609/android-wear-listen-to-incoming-notifications/38794028#38794028).